# Render View with Json Result

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im wondering is it possible to render a view from a json result, basically when the user clicks on a button in my view, i want to go and fetch data from my controller/model using json result, with this data i want to open a view with the new data, is this possible?

**AJax Call**

```
 $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAdminSubmissions", "Inspections")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: JSON,
        data: { 'selectedDepartment': deparment, 'searchDate': selectedDate },
        success: function (result) {

            // on success open view with new updated model

        },
        error: function (result) {

            alert(result);
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public JsonResult GetAdminSubmissions(string selectedDepartment, string searchDate)
    {
        var result = new List<Checks_Records>();

        if (searchDate != null)
        {
            var enUkCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            var userSelectedDate = DateTime.Today.Date.AddHours(7);

            DateTime parsedDate;

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(searchDate, "dd-MMMM-yyyy", enUkCultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
            {
                userSelectedDate = parsedDate.AddHours(7);

                result = Model.GetListofChecks_Records(userSelectedDate, selectedDepartment);

                var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
                return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        return error;
    }
```

Comment: Just make an action that returns a view-bound result `return View(json, "view_name")`

Comment: You could always construct the html in JavaScript. It's simple enough with jQuery and if the "view" isn't very big.

Comment: Depending what you want to return (full view or partial view), there always having another method which renders it, possibly using `ActionLink` which passing JSON output as action arguments.

Comment: You are getting Json data as result in ajax call.
Use javascript to create html elements and put result data as u like.
I think with ajax u can render only partial view.